# Subtraction of two positive semidefinite

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, symmetric-matrices, positive-semidefinite

Let $A$, $B$ be two positive semidefinite matrices. Is matrix $$C := A - B$$ positive semidefinite if all of $C$'s entries are non-negative? If not, what if both $A$ and $B$ are non-negative?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo whoops, the condition should be knowing $A-B\geq 0$,  the question has been modified.

Comment: No. Consider $\pmatrix{0&1\\ 1&0}=\pmatrix{1&1\\ 1&1}-\pmatrix{1&0\\ 0&1}.$

Comment: [Doubly nonnegative matrix](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DoublyNonnegativeMatrix.html)